# C# first time I use GetRequestStream() it takes 20 seconds

Tags: c#

I use C#.

The first time I use WebRequest GetRequestStream() in my code, it takes up to 20 seconds. After that it takes it takes under 1 second.

Below is my code. The row "this.requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream()" is causing the delay.

```
StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder(100);
postData.Append("param=");
postData.Append("test");
byte[] dataArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData.ToString());

this.httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://myurl.com");

httpRequest.Method = "POST";
httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

httpRequest.ContentLength = dataArray.Length;

this.requestStream = httpRequest.GetRequestStream();

using (requestStream)
    requestStream.Write(dataArray, 0, dataArray.Length);

this.webResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

Stream responseStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader responseReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
String responseString = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
```

How can I see what causes this? (for instance: DNS lookup? Server not responding?)

Thanks and regards, Koen

Comment: It actually happens to be a problem related to VMWare NAT network. I still think it is weird though.

Comment: I'm not seeing the long delay the first time, but it seems to grow with each request.  GetRequestStream is taking about twice as long as GetResponse.

Comment: (Setting Proxy to null doesn't seem to help much.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could also try to set the .Proxy = null. Sometimes it tries to autodetect a proxy which takes up time.

Comment: This was it. Thanks so much!
Take proxy detection took 20 seconds.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like your application is pre-compiling when you first hit it. This is how .net works.

Here is a way to speed up your web app. [link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972.aspx)

Comment: It is actually a Windows service. It happens everytime I start the service, not just after it has been compiled.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually the framework for HTML operations doing startup network proxy checking to setup the property `HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy`.

In my application as part of the startup actions I create a fully formed request as a back ground task to get this overhead out of the way.

```
HttpWebRequest web = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(m_ServletURL);
web.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (Windows 7 6.1) Java/1.6.0_26";
```

Setting the UserAgent field in my case is triggers the startup overhead.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but `.proxy = null` didn't solve it for me. Depending on the network structure the problem might be connected to IPv6. The first request nearly took exactly 21sec each time the application run. Therefore I argue it must be a timeout value. If this value is reached the fallback solution IPv4 is used (for subsequent calls as well). Forcing the use of IPv4 in the first place solved the issue for me!

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://myurl.com") as HttpWebRequest;
request.ServicePoint.BindIPEndPointDelegate = (servicePount, remoteEndPoint, retryCount) =>
{
    if (remoteEndPoint.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
    {
        return new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
    }
    throw new System.InvalidOperationException("No IPv4 address found.");
};
```

Comment: The only solution that worked for me! I tried everything. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

One problem may be the fact that [.NET, by default, only allows 2 connections at a time](http://en.code-bude.net/tag/httpwebrequest-getrequeststream-slow/).

You can increase the number of simultaneous connections with:

```
 ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = newConnectionLimit;
```

We leave the determination of the optimal value to the user.